# How do I change the size of a row to match the size of the columns?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to use PyQt5 a little bit unconventionally here in order to make the table completely square in order to make a board game layout in PyQt5. I know how to change the size of the columns to stretch to fill the window, but I have no idea how to do that for the rows.
How do I make it so that the height and length of each cell is the same? I assume that the screen it's on will not always be square, so how do I make sure that the user wouldn't have to scroll to see the whole screen?

Thank you!

Here's my code so far:

```
def createTable(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
  
        #Row and column count
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(9)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(9)  

        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem())

        header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        for i in range(9):       
            header.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

I haven't been able to find code that would do the same thing as QHeaderView, and I was wondering if it existed or if there was an alternative.

Comment: Do the same for `self.tableWidget.verticalHeader()`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.